# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm pretty new to Python and Selenium. I was following a tutorial on how to code an Instagram bot to gain followers and likes.

The program opens a Firefox window as it should, but then when it has to fill in the username and password field it does nothing. Then when i close down the window i find myself with this error.

It's really odd that i get this error because i reviewed the elements on https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ and in the username field there was a name='username' as well as an name='password' in the password field.

Can anybody help me out?

This is a piece of the code:

```
class InstagramBot:

def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    self.login()

def login(self):
    self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

    self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)

    self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
```

This is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Python Programming/PycharmProjects/insta_bot/bot.py", line 25, in <module>
    ig_bot = InstagramBot('temp_username', 'temp_password')
  File "C:/Users/Python Programming/PycharmProjects/insta_bot/bot.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.login()
  File "C:/Users/Python Programming/PycharmProjects/insta_bot/bot.py", line 19, in login
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
  File "C:\Users\Python Programming\PycharmProjects\insta_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Python Programming\PycharmProjects\insta_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Python Programming\PycharmProjects\insta_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Python Programming\PycharmProjects\insta_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]
```

Comment: That element isn't present when the page first loads; it is added to the page dynamically with javascript.  You'll have to tell Selenium to wait a few moments before looking for the element.  See http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you may need to wait for some scripts on the page to finish before that element exists.

here are the import statements you'll need:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Use this code to wait for that element before your `send_keys` line:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
```

Comment: Also, `how to code an Instagram bot to gain followers and likes` sounds ethically questionable. Be careful out there :)

Comment: Good point. about the `wait` I think it should be more like 10 you know connection issues...

Comment: @MosheSlavin good point, updated from 5 -> 10 assuming this isn't testing for good performance and this code should be more focused on dealing with issues (as opposed to test code focusing on finding issues)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It worked! You only forgot to note that i also had to import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` else it won't work

Comment: @MosheSlavin It shouldn't be 5 or 10 as such. It should come from the design documents which should specify the max time limit for desired elements to be interactable when 1) New website loads and 2) Subpages of the website loads.